# Cannot Copy a file from a network share in powershell until I open the share in windows explorer

Tags: powershell

I have a very simple powershell script which to copy files from a networked server.

here's the script

```
Write-Output "Copying Backups"
copy \\sqlbox\SqlBackups\Client.bak c:\sqlbackups
```

It throws this exception

```
Invalid Path: '\\sqlbox\SqlBackups\Client.bak'.
At C:\Work\db\restore.ps1:5 char:1
+ copy \\sqlbox\SqlBackups\Client.bak c:\sqlbackups
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], ArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyItemDynamicParametersProviderException
```

If I open a windows explorer up and goto \sqlbox\SqlBackups it opens fine and if I then run the powershel script it also starts working and will work until the next time I reboot the PC.

How can I address this in the script?

Comment: When you open the share from the explorer for the first time after a reboot, are you prompted to enter a username and password?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help on Powershell Copy-Item from network drives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653851/need-help-on-powershell-copy-item-from-network-drives)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try mapping the drive first, then carry out the copy operation.

```
New-PSDrive -Name S -Root \\sqlbox\SqlBackups\ -PSProvider FileSystem
Write-Output "Copying Backups"
copy S:\Client.bak c:\sqlbackups
```

Comment: What does mapping the drive do?

Comment: It will create a virtual drive letter "S:" that will point to \\sqlbox\SqlBackups.
It's just a different approach to achieve the same thing, but hopefully it will eliminate the error.
Have you tried it?

Comment: Can you make a nameless UNC mapping? like `net use \\sqlbox\SqlBackups\ ` Would it work too?

Comment: says drive S does not exist 
i tried creating drive from remote desktop as well but still can not use it

Answer (score 6):

I have a similar problem when copying files over servers with this error:

> Cannot find path '\\computer1\d$\path' because it does not exist.

It **works after adding** `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::` in front of file name:

```
copy-item "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\computer1\d$\path\installer.msi" "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\computer2\d$\path\installer.msi"
```

Comment: I think it's better and more simple way to achieve desired result than mapping a drive.