# How do you copy a file from your computer to a remote computer using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a file on my computer that I would like to remotely put onto another computer on the network. I've tried to use Copy-Item and do it while in a PS-Session but it doesn't work that way. Thanks!

Edit: Duplicate Question

Comment: show us your code so far

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need help on Powershell Copy-Item from network drives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653851/need-help-on-powershell-copy-item-from-network-drives)

Comment: Thank you @Raf, I searched for it but couldn't find what I was looking for. I figured it was here somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
copy-item "C:\Local Directory\filename.txt" "\\remotecomputer\C$\Remote Directory"
```

The most common prerequisite is that you are a member of the local Administrators group on the remote computer.